# Log4j LocationInfo Struts + Tomcat slowness

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, profile, visualvm

I have developed a web app using log4j-1.2.14.jar, and I am seeing that
org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo is taking up 76% of my CPU time.

I have checked Java VisualVM

[image: The problem]

Can anybody helps me in order to improve the efficience of my web app

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1):

In your conversion pattern you are probably using a conversion character in your PatternLayout that you should not use.

The conversion patterns that make your performance bad are:

- `%l` combined package, class, method and line number. The documentation says 'its generation is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue'
- `%F` filename
- `%L` linenumber
- `%C` classname (rather use %c)
- `%F` filename
- `%M` method name

Also rather use `%d{ISO8601}`, `%d{DATE}` or `%d{ABSOLUTE}` than something like `%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}`. But that performance penalty is not as dramatic as that of the conversion patterns mentioned above.

See the warnings about slow performance in the log4j help: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html