# Log4j Additivity

Tags: java, log4j

i have this log4j properties and i want to prevent rootLogger from duplicate messages of the other appenders, i have tried with additivity but it doesnt work

Any help?

```
**log4j.additivity.appender.appenderProcesoWREG=false**
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file.File = C\:\\datos\\logs\\loging.log

log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=ERROR
log4j.logger.ognl=ERROR

log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern = '.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd/MM HH:mm:ss} %-5p ([%-30F]:%-30M) = %m %n

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %p [%t, %c] - %m%n



log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg.File = C\:\\OEGAM_FILES\\FICHEROS_LOGS\\PROCESO_WREG\\LOCAL\\procesoWreg.log
log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd/MM HH:mm:ss} %-5p ([%-30F]:%-30M) = %m %n
log4j.logger.ProcesoWreg = INFO,appenderProcesoWreg
```

Comment: Possible related/duplicate of: [Log4j LocationInfo Struts + Tomcat slowness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885758/log4j-locationinfo-struts-tomcat-slowness)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was :

**log4j.additivity.appender.appenderProcesoWREG=false**

I have changed it for:

```
log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg.File = C\:\\OEGAM_FILES\\FICHEROS_LOGS\\PROCESO_WREG\\LOCAL\\procesoWreg.log
log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.appenderProcesoWreg.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{dd/MM HH:mm:ss} %-5p ([%-30F]:%-30M) = %m %n
log4j.logger.ProcesoWreg = INFO,appenderProcesoWreg
log4j.additivity.PocesoWreg = false
```

And it works perfect